# Python type() not giving exact class type instead gives metaclass type

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass, method-resolution-order, six

I am trying to pass the type of a class to a method so that it can be dynamically instantiated. The class extends to a base class which further extends to an abstract class. Now when I check the type of my class it comes as the abstract class type instead of the child class.

Here is how my classes look like

```
class AMeta(type):
     # stuff

class Parent(six.with_metaclass(AMeta, object)):
     # stuff

class Child(Parent):
    # stuff
```

Now when I use `type(Child) or Child.__class__` it gives me `AMeta` whereas I would like to get `Child`. I want to pass this Child to another method which would dynamically create its object.

```
def create_obj(clzz):
   return clzz()
```

When I call the method like `create_obj(type(Child))` it doesn't work and breaks but when I call `Child.mro()[0]` it works fine what is happening here and is there another way to achieve what I am achieving via mro method?

Comment: So you want `create_obj(Child)`? Is that it? Did I understand this right? (`Child.mro()[0]` is `Child` by the way.)

Comment: Yes I would like to do that only, I could also use type(name, bases, dict) to create the class dynamically but I would prefer the 1st approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class is an instance of its metaclass.  Ergo:

- The type of `Child` is `AMeta`
- The type of a `Child()` is `Child`

Comment: Hi @wim thanks for the quick response, but I cannot directly create Child() as it requires few mandatory args while instantiating whose value I retrieve in the create_obj method is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Pass the arguments into `create_obj` and use them in the call `clzz(...)`

Comment: @wim In other words: Get rid of the `create_obj` function because it's useless?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  Presumably, it has some extra logic in it, or is used from a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `type(Child)`, you are asking what is the `type` of your `Child` **class**. Keep in mind that classes are also *instances* in Python. When in your script you do `class Child...`, there is a new name (`Child`) added to the script's namespace (pretty much a variable called `Child` of type `AMeta` since you're specifying that `AMeta` is the metaclass of `Child`. Otherwise, it would be of type `type` which is a bit like the "default" metaclass)

See:

```
import six

class AMeta(type):
     pass

class Parent(six.with_metaclass(AMeta, object)):
     pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass

print(type(Child))
c=Child()
print(type(c))
```

In the first print, you get `<class '__main__.AMeta'>` because you're asking *What is the type of my Child **instance**?*. In the second print you get `<class '__main__.Child'>` because you're asking *What is the type of my `c` **instance**?*

You don't need to do `type(Child)` to get the class. You can use it directly. For instance:

```
obj = Child
dynamic_instance = obj()
print(type(dynamic_instance))
```

Will print `<class '__main__.Child'>`

Closer to you example, that'd be:

```
def create_obj(clzz):
   return clzz()

a = create_obj(Child)
print("Just created: %s" % type(a))
```

Which outputs `Just created: <class '__main__.Child'>`